content layer3 with nextjs 14 app router I’m encountering an error when running contentlayer build on Windows. The error message is:
I’m encountering an error when running contentlayer build on Windows. The error message is:
TypeError: The "code" argument must be of type number. Received an instance of Object
    at process.set [as exitCode] (node:internal/bootstrap/node:123:9)
    at Cli.runExit (D:\Code\Webdev\unicorn-space-ui\node_modules\.pnpm\clipanion@3.2.1_typanion@3.14.0\node_modules\clipanion\lib\advanced\Cli.js:232:26)
    at run (file:///D:/Code/Webdev/unicorn-space-ui/node_modules/.pnpm/@contentlayer+cli@0.3.4_esbuild@0.18.20/node_modules/@contentlayer/cli/src/index.ts:39:3)
    at main (D:\Code\Webdev\unicorn-space-ui\node_modules\.pnpm\contentlayer@0.3.4_esbuild@0.18.20\node_modules\contentlayer\bin\cli.cjs:5:3) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}



Contentlayer version: 0.3.4
Node.js version: [Your Node.js version]
Operating System: Windows 10

Steps to reproduce:
Run pnpm exec contentlayer build in the project directory.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
I tried clearing the next cache, pnpm cache, deleted node_modules stuff,
